# Issue using JavaScript and JQuery in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code:

```
<blink>

    <head>
    <title>Dark</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/button.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/button.js"></script>

    <p class="one btnall"> Text1 </p>
    <p class="two btnall">Text2 </p>
    <p class="three btnall"> Text 3 </p>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="btn1">Button 1</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="btn2">Button 2</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="btn3">Button 3</a>


    </body>
    </html>
</blink>
```

And my JavaScript or JQuery (I'm not sure because I copied from internet) code:

```
$('.one').hide();
$('.two').hide();
$('.three').hide();
$('.btnall').hide();
$('.btn1').click(function () {
    $('.btnall').fadeOut();
    $('.one').fadeIn();
});

$('.btn2').click(function () {
    $('.btnall').fadeOut();
    $('.two').fadeIn();

});

$('.btn3').click(function () {
    $('.btnall').fadeOut();
    $('.three').fadeIn();
});
```

The problem is the code doesn't work on website. The code belongs to some buttons which fade some texts.

Comment: have you put this code within `document.ready`   ??

Comment: Yes, wrap your code in `<script>` tag first and then in `$(document).ready();`. And you must include jQuery file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in `ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/ready

Also, you have included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/button.js"></script>
```

twice.

First in `head`  and at the start of `body`.

Remove one and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Place your entire jQuery code in document.ready block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.one').hide();
      $('.two').hide();
      $('.three').hide();
      $('.btnall').hide();
      $('.btn1').click(function() {
          $('.btnall').fadeOut();
          $('.one').fadeIn();
      });

      $('.btn2').click(function() {
          $('.btnall').fadeOut();
          $('.two').fadeIn();

      });

      $('.btn3').click(function() {
          $('.btnall').fadeOut();
          $('.three').fadeIn();
      });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use place your code within

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //code
});
```

and place your code before end of the body tag like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.one').hide();
        $('.two').hide();
        $('.three').hide();
        $('.btnall').hide();
        $('.btn1').click(function () {
        $('.btnall').fadeOut();
        $('.one').fadeIn();
        });

        $('.btn2').click(function () {
        $('.btnall').fadeOut();
        $('.two').fadeIn();

        $('.btn3').click(function () {
        $('.btnall').fadeOut();
        $('.three').fadeIn();
        });

    });

    });
    </script>
        </body>
```

Now it will work or you can place your js code in seperate js file and link through `<script src="your_path/your_js.js"></script>` before `</body>`